# has term or has tag doesn't work in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to check from child functions if product category is "test-cat" or tag "test-tag" but nothing doesn't work

```
if( is_tax( "product_cat","test-cat")){
echo "<h1>BLA</h1>";
}

if( is_product_category("test-cat")){
 echo "<h1>BLA</h1>";
}

if( has_term("disable-all-products", "test-cat")) {
 echo "<h1>BLA</h1>";
}

if( is_product_tag("test-tag")) { 
 echo "<h1>BLA</h1>";
}
```

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 0):

If I add this in the function :

```
if(is_product_category("test-cat") {
  // ...
}
```

Then I call it through the hook it's working like it should.